# Wordpress - Customizing CSS Filters

Tags: php, css, wordpress, filter

I'm running Wordpress 4.1 with the TinyMCE editor. In the TinyMCE editor, I've enabled the Advanced Lists plugin, which allows customizing the list style type of list items (ex. `<li style="list-style-type: lower-alpha">`).

When I submit a post with a modified list style, the `list-style-type` declaration gets stripped out, but other CSS declarations are just fine (ex. `text-align`).

Looking at the Wordpress source, the CSS is being filtered by the `safecss_filter_attr()` function in `kses.php`. In `safecss_filter_attr()` I can see an array of CSS declarations. If I add `list-style-type` to that array, I can then save my post, and `list-style-type` is no longer filtered out.

However, editing the Wordpress source isn't maintainable, as it'll eventually be overwritten when Wordpress is upgraded. So, my question is this: How do I prevent Wordpress from filtering out the `list-style-type` CSS declaration in a maintainable fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That array you are editing is actually being passed as a parameter to the `'safe_style_css'` filter. The return value of `'safe_style_css'` is being stored in `$allowed_attr`. (Line 1482 in kses.php)

So in your functions.php, write a function that looks something like this.

```
function my_css_allow($allowed_attr) {

    if (!is_array($allowed_attr)) {
        $allowed_attr = array();
    }

    $allowed_attr[] = 'list-style-type';

    return $allowed_attr;
}

add_filter('safe_style_css','my_css_allow');
```

I've not tested that but it looks like it should work.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Fantastic, that worked perfectly. I'm going to have to read up on filters, as I don't understand them well enough. Also, your code is almost perfect, except for a missing `)` on line 3, and an extra `'` on the last line;